# Calculate Daily Average Sales for top 3 products based on multiple conditions

Tags: excel

I have an excel product sales table looking like this (last column is empty, i've just populated the result I'm looking to calculate):

| Date | Sales | Retailer | ProductName | ProductType | Top 3 daily AVG Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 | 1000 | Retailer 1 | Product 1 | Mobile | 2100 |
| 01/01/2021 | 2000 | Retailer 1 | Product 2 | Desktop |  |
| 01/01/2021 | 700 | Retailer 1 | Product 3 | Desktop |  |
| 01/01/2021 | 1250 | Retailer 1 | Product 4 | Mobile | 2100 |
| 01/01/2021 | 2200 | Retailer 1 | Product 5 | Mobile | 2100 |
| 01/01/2021 | 1700 | Retailer 1 | Product 6 | Desktop |  |
| 01/01/2021 | 2700 | Retailer 1 | Product 7 | Mobile | 2100 |
| 01/01/2021 | 1400 | Retailer 1 | Product 8 | Mobile | 2100 |
| 01/01/2021 | 1200 | Retailer 1 | Product 9 | Desktop |  |
| 01/01/2021 | 1650 | Retailer 1 | Product 10 | Desktop |  |
| 01/01/2021 | 1200 | Retailer 2 | Product 1 | Mobile |  |
| 01/01/2021 | 1000 | Retailer 2 | Product 2 | Desktop |  |
| 01/01/2021 | 600 | Retailer 2 | Product 3 | Desktop |  |
| 01/01/2021 | 2250 | Retailer 2 | Product 4 | Mobile |  |
| 01/01/2021 | 1450 | Retailer 2 | Product 5 | Mobile |  |
| 01/01/2021 | 1600 | Retailer 2 | Product 6 | Desktop |  |
| 01/01/2021 | 1700 | Retailer 2 | Product 7 | Mobile |  |
| 01/01/2021 | 1800 | Retailer 2 | Product 8 | Mobile |  |
| 01/01/2021 | 1300 | Retailer 2 | Product 9 | Desktop |  |
| 01/01/2021 | 1100 | Retailer 2 | Product 10 | Desktop |  |
| 01/02/2021 | 1000 | Retailer 1 | Product 1 | Mobile |  |
| 01/02/2021 | 2000 | Retailer 1 | Product 2 | Desktop |  |
| 01/02/2021 | 700 | Retailer 1 | Product 3 | Desktop |  |
| 01/02/2021 | 1250 | Retailer 1 | Product 4 | Mobile |  |
| 01/02/2021 | 2200 | Retailer 1 | Product 5 | Mobile |  |
| 01/02/2021 | 1700 | Retailer 1 | Product 6 | Desktop |  |
| 01/02/2021 | 2700 | Retailer 1 | Product 7 | Mobile |  |
| 01/02/2021 | 1400 | Retailer 1 | Product 8 | Mobile |  |
| 01/02/2021 | 1200 | Retailer 1 | Product 9 | Desktop |  |
| 01/02/2021 | 1650 | Retailer 1 | Product 10 | Desktop |  |
| 01/02/2021 | 1200 | Retailer 2 | Product 1 | Mobile |  |
| 01/02/2021 | 1000 | Retailer 2 | Product 2 | Desktop |  |
| 01/02/2021 | 600 | Retailer 2 | Product 3 | Desktop |  |
| 01/02/2021 | 2250 | Retailer 2 | Product 4 | Mobile |  |
| 01/02/2021 | 1450 | Retailer 2 | Product 5 | Mobile |  |
| 01/02/2021 | 1600 | Retailer 2 | Product 6 | Desktop |  |
| 01/02/2021 | 1700 | Retailer 2 | Product 7 | Mobile |  |
| 01/02/2021 | 1800 | Retailer 2 | Product 8 | Mobile |  |
| 01/02/2021 | 1300 | Retailer 2 | Product 9 | Desktop |  |
| 01/02/2021 | 1100 | Retailer 2 | Product 10 | Desktop |  |

In the Top 3 daily AVG Sales column I'm looking to write a formula that calculates the average top 3 sales for each day per Retailer and Product Type. So, if date is 01/01/2021 and Retailer is Retailer 1 and ProductType is Mobile, find the top 3 sales and average them => (2200+2700+1400)/3 = 2100

Appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try-

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(SORT(FILTER($B$3:$B$42,($A$3:$A$42=A3)*($C$3:$C$42=C3)*($E$3:$E$42=E3)),,-1),{1,2,3}))
```

> Edit: Try below array formula for non `O365` excels. Must be enters nu `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`.

```
=AVERAGE(LARGE(IF(($A$2:$A$42=A2)*($C$2:$C$42=C2)*($E$2:$E$42=E2),$B$2:$B$42,""),{1,2,3}))
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formula as it is an array formula.

[image]

Comment: I am using MS Office Home&Business 2019 and don't have sort and filter available. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Then we need to use some other array formula. I will post later as I am writing from mobile now.

Comment: @user15005160 Please try my edited answer.